# Filter listview using a select

Tags: jquery-mobile

With jquery mobile its possible filter a `listview` using a select control?

this is my example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdEKd/7/)

Selecting an option the listview must be filtered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the filter to true `data-filter="true"` and then manually hide it.

```
#myContent .ui-listview-filter {
    display: none;
}
```

On change of select, just put the selected value into the text field and trigger `keyup` event.

```
$('#select-choice-1').change(function() {
    $('#myContent .ui-listview-filter input.ui-input-text').val($(this).val()).trigger('keyup');
});
```

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/gdEKd/9/

Answer (score 2):

See updated demo : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdEKd/8/)

```
<ul data-role="listview">
   <li data-filtertext="de" class="de"><a href=#>Audi</a></li>
   <li data-filtertext="de" class="de"><a href=#>BMW</a></li>
   <li data-filtertext="it" class="it"><a href=#>Ferrari</a></li>
   <li data-filtertext="it" class="it"><a href=#>Lamborghini</a></li>
   <li data-filtertext="it" class="it"><a href=#>Maserati</a></li>
</ul>

$('#select-choice-1').change(function(){
    var value = $('#select-choice-1').val();
    $("ul").find("li").hide()
    $("ul").find("li."+value).show();
  });
```